# How to increase the header size in ion-action-sheet in ionic frame work vuejs

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, ionic-framework, vue-component

I'm new to Vue. Using ionic framework. I have the below code in my application

```html
<ion-action-sheet
  :is-open="isActionSheetOpen"
  header="Choose Payment"
  mode="ios"
  :buttons="buttons"
  @didDismiss="setOpen(false)"
  class="my-custom-class"
></ion-action-sheet>
```

I want to increase the font size of the `header="Choose Payment"` to 25px. I've not found any official documentation regarding the increase in the size of the header.

How should I do it?

I've tried to add the custom CSS for the class below

```css
ion-action-sheet.my-custom-class {
  --font-size: 25px;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have already specified a cssClass to apply to the action sheet, targeting the css class of title element should be enough:

```css
ion-action-sheet.my-custom-class .action-sheet-title {
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

Check the [IonActionSheet docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/action-sheet#styling), you can see a modified version of the docs' examples that cover your use case [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/3dkq21?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FExample.vue).